# Input field taking pasted arabic text in a wrong format

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an inputfield.When I paste a engish text in it, it is in correct a format which is not happenning for arabic text.Is anything has to be done for getting proper pasted text of arabic text.

Ex:Anything other than Arabic 
   pasted text `English` and displaying text `English`.
   Arabic
   pasted text `أسبوع` it is displaying in in reverse order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unity don't support right to left languages like Arabic or Persian.

**UPDATED**

check this plugin first:

> Right-To-Left Text Mesh Pro for Unity. This plugin adds support for
>   Persian and Arabic languages to TextMeshPro.

https://github.com/sorencoder/RTLTMPro

**OLD**

use this site for convert your text to right to left version :

[online rtl text convertor](http://bobardo.com/reshaper/)

copy your text in first text-box and get you converted version from second one.

---

or download this app :

[maryam rtl convertor](http://dl.taktemp.com/dl2/Maryam%20Soft%20[www.TakTemp.com].zip)

---

or use this class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace System.Collections
{
    public static class Fa {

        public static Dictionary <int,int[]> charStorage = new Dictionary<int, int[]> ()
        {
            {65165, new int[] {65165, 65166, 65165, 65166}},    {65167, new int[] {65167, 65168, 65169, 65170}},    {64342, new int[] {64342, 64343, 64344, 64345}},    {65173, new int[] {65173, 65174, 65175, 65176}},    {65177, new int[] {65177, 65178, 65179, 65180}},    {65181, new int[] {65181, 65182, 65183, 65184}},    {64378, new int[] {64378, 64379, 64380, 64381}},    {65185, new int[] {65185, 65186, 65187, 65188}},    {65189, new int[] {65189, 65190, 65191, 65192}},    {65193, new int[] {65193, 65194, 65193, 65194}},    {65195, new int[] {65195, 65196, 65195, 65196}},    {65197, new int[] {65197, 65198, 65197, 65198}},    {65199, new int[] {65199, 65200, 65199, 65200}},    {64394, new int[] {64394, 64395, 64394, 64395}},    {65201, new int[] {65201, 65202, 65203, 65204}},    {65205, new int[] {65205, 65206, 65207, 65208}},    {65209, new int[] {65209, 65210, 65211, 65212}},    {65213, new int[] {65213, 65214, 65215, 65216}},    {65217, new int[] {65217, 65218, 65219, 65220}},    {65221, new int[] {65221, 65222, 65223, 65224}},    {65225, new int[] {65225, 65226, 65227, 65228}},    {65229, new int[] {65229, 65230, 65231, 65232}},    {65233, new int[] {65233, 65234, 65235, 65236}},    {65237, new int[] {65237, 65238, 65239, 65240}},    {64398, new int[] {64398, 64399, 64400, 64401}},    {64402, new int[] {64402, 64403, 64404, 64405}},    {65245, new int[] {65245, 65246, 65247, 65248}},    {65249, new int[] {65249, 65250, 65251, 65252}},    {65253, new int[] {65253, 65254, 65255, 65256}},    {65261, new int[] {65261, 65262, 65261, 65262}},    {65257, new int[] {65257, 65258, 65259, 65260}},    {64508, new int[] {64508, 64509, 64510, 64511}},    {65153, new int[] {65153, 65154, 65153, 65154}},
            {1575, new int[] {1575, 65166, 65165, 65166}},  {1576, new int[] {1576, 65168, 65169, 65170}},  {1662, new int[] {1662, 64343, 64344, 64345}},  {1578, new int[] {1578, 65174, 65175, 65176}},  {1579, new int[] {1579, 65178, 65179, 65180}},  {1580, new int[] {1580, 65182, 65183, 65184}},  {1670, new int[] {1670, 64379, 64380, 64381}},  {1581, new int[] {1581, 65186, 65187, 65188}},  {1582, new int[] {1582, 65190, 65191, 65192}},  {1583, new int[] {1583, 65194, 65193, 65194}},  {1584, new int[] {1584, 65196, 65195, 65196}},  {1585, new int[] {1585, 65198, 65197, 65198}},  {1586, new int[] {1586, 65200, 65199, 65200}},  {1688, new int[] {1688, 64395, 64394, 64395}},  {1587, new int[] {1587, 65202, 65203, 65204}},  {1588, new int[] {1588, 65206, 65207, 65208}},  {1589, new int[] {1589, 65210, 65211, 65212}},  {1590, new int[] {1590, 65214, 65215, 65216}},  {1591, new int[] {1591, 65218, 65219, 65220}},  {1592, new int[] {1592, 65222, 65223, 65224}},  {1593, new int[] {1593, 65226, 65227, 65228}},  {1594, new int[] {1594, 65230, 65231, 65232}},  {1601, new int[] {1601, 65234, 65235, 65236}},  {1602, new int[] {1602, 65238, 65239, 65240}},  {1705, new int[] {1705, 64399, 64400, 64401}},  {1711, new int[] {1711, 64403, 64404, 64405}},  {1604, new int[] {1604, 65246, 65247, 65248}},  {1605, new int[] {1605, 65250, 65251, 65252}},  {1606, new int[] {1606, 65254, 65255, 65256}},  {1608, new int[] {1608, 65262, 65261, 65262}},  {1607, new int[] {1607, 65258, 65259, 65260}},  {1740, new int[] {1740, 64509, 64510, 64511}},  {1570, new int[] {1570, 65154, 65153, 65154}},

            {65265, new int[] {65265, 65266, 65267, 65268}}, {65171, new int[] {65171, 65172, 65171, 65172}}, {65263, new int[] {65263, 65264, 65263, 65264}},  {65157, new int[] {65157, 65158, 65157, 65158}},    {65155, new int[] {65155, 65156, 65155, 65156}},    {65159, new int[] {65159, 65160, 65159, 65160}},    {65241, new int[] {65241, 65242, 65243, 65244}},    {65161, new int[] {65161, 65162, 65163, 65164}},
            {1610, new int[] {65265, 65266, 65267, 65268}}, {1577, new int[] {65171, 65172, 65171, 65172}}, {1609, new int[] {65263, 65264, 65263, 65264}}, {1572, new int[] {65157, 65158, 65157, 65158}}, {1571, new int[] {65155, 65156, 65155, 65156}}, {1573, new int[] {65159, 65160, 65159, 65160}}, {1603, new int[] {65241, 65242, 65243, 65244}}, {1574, new int[] {65161, 65162, 65163, 65164}},

        };

        public static Dictionary <int,int[]> boolStorage = new Dictionary<int, int[]> ()
        {
            {65165, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65167, new int[] {1, 1}},  {64342, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65173, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65177, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65181, new int[] {1, 1}},  {64378, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65185, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65189, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65193, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65195, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65197, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65199, new int[] {0, 1}},  {64394, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65201, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65205, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65209, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65213, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65217, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65221, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65225, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65229, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65233, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65237, new int[] {1, 1}},  {64398, new int[] {1, 1}},  {64402, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65245, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65249, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65253, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65261, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65257, new int[] {1, 1}},  {64508, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65153, new int[] {0, 1}}, 
            {1575, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1576, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1662, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1578, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1579, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1580, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1670, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1581, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1582, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1583, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1584, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1585, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1586, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1688, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1587, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1588, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1589, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1590, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1591, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1592, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1593, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1594, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1601, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1602, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1705, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1711, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1604, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1605, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1606, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1608, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1607, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1740, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1570, new int[] {0, 1}}, 

            {65265, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65171, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65263, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65157, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65155, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65159, new int[] {0, 1}},  {65241, new int[] {1, 1}},  {65161, new int[] {1, 1}}, 
            {1610, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1577, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1609, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1572, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1571, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1573, new int[] {0, 1}},   {1603, new int[] {1, 1}},   {1574, new int[] {1, 1}}, 

        };

        public static string faConvert(this string input)
        {
            string outStr = "";
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(input))
            {
                string line;
                bool more = false;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (more) outStr += "\n";
                    outStr += faConvertLine(line);
                    more = true;
                }
            }

            char[] eng = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
            char[] fa = { '٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩' };

            for (int i = 0; i < eng.Length; i++)
            {
                outStr = outStr.Replace(eng[i], fa[i]);
            }

            return outStr;
        }

        public static string faConvertLine(string input)
        {
            char[] charTemp = input.ToCharArray ();

            char chT;
            List<char> listT = new List<char>();
            List<char> listF = new List<char>();
            for (int i=0; i < charTemp.Length; i++)
            {
                if (isFarsi(charTemp[i]))
                {
                    chT = convertChar((i==0)?0:Convert.ToInt32(charTemp[i-1]),
                                      Convert.ToInt32(charTemp[i]),
                                      (i==charTemp.Length-1)?0:Convert.ToInt32(charTemp[i+1]));

                    listT.Reverse();
                    listF.AddRange(listT);
                    listF.Add(chT);

                    listT.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    listT.Add(charTemp[i]);
                }
            }

            listT.Reverse();
            listF.AddRange(listT);
            listF.Reverse();
            return new string (listF.ToArray());
        }

        public static char convertChar(int prev, int curr, int next)
        {

            int pr=0, ne=0;
            int[] tmp; int[] ctmp;

            if (boolStorage.TryGetValue (prev, out tmp))
                pr = tmp[0];
            else
                pr = 0;

            if (boolStorage.TryGetValue (next, out tmp))
                ne = tmp[1];
            else
                ne = 0;

            if (charStorage.TryGetValue(curr, out ctmp))
                return Char.ConvertFromUtf32(ctmp [pr + (ne * 2)])[0];
            else
                return Char.ConvertFromUtf32(curr)[0];
        }

        public static bool isFarsi(char ch)
        {
            int ch16 = Convert.ToInt32(ch);
            if ((ch16 >= 1536 && ch16 <= 1791) || (ch16 >= 65136 && ch16 <= 65279))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
txtMessage.text = Fa.faConvert("أسبوع");
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you fix the Arabic text

https://github.com/Konash/arabic-support-unity/blob/master/Assets/ArabicSupport/Scripts/ArabicSupport.cs

And don't forget to use a **font** that supports Arabic language.

use example:

```
string myText = textObject.text;

textObject.text = ArabicFixer.Fix(txt, true);
```